# Subtract sets after filtering in VBA

Tags: excel, filter, set, subtraction, vba

I would like to subtract 2 ranges (sets) from each other. The minuend (range from which to subtract) contains the subtrahend (range to be subtracted), which creates a positive remainder range. Note that minuend (base) consists of filtered cells, which are not necessarily connected with each other. See more on that below, after the introductory example.

For example assume the minuend ist as follows:

```
x1  x2  x3
A   A   A
A   A   B
A   A   C
```

The subtrahend is as follows, where `-` stands for nothing and is just used for illustration of positioning:

```
x1  x2  x3
-   -   A
-   -   -
-   -   C
```

Then the remainder should be as follows:

```
x1  x2  x3
A   A   -
A   A   B
A   A   -
```

One important thing to mention is, that the lines are separated by **hidden rows** due to using a filter before doing the subtraction, see the following example which you can use in Excel/VBA:

```
X1  X2  X3
12  13  B
12  15  C
12  15  D
12  15  E
12  15  F
13  15  G
13  15  H
13  13  I
13  15  J
13  15  K
13  15  L
13  15  M
13  13  N
13  15  O
13  15  P
13  15  Q
13  15  R
13  14  S
```

First I filter the second column to display only "13". This yields:

```
X1  X2  X3
12  13  B
13  13  I
13  13  N
```

Then let's say I want to subtract `Cells(2,3)` which is `B` and `Cells(14,3)` which is `N` from the above displayed range, or illustrated in the same way as before:

```
X1  X2  X3
-   -   B
-   -   -
-   -   N
```

Then the result should be:

```
X1  X2  X3
12  13  -
13  13  I
13  13  -
```

The code to achieve this (unfinished):

```
Sub TestingStuff()

Dim y As Integer
Dim x1 As Range, x2 As Range, xs As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.UsedRange
rng.AutoFilter
rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="13"

Dim myR As Range: Set myR = ws.UsedRange

Set x1 = myR.Offset(1, 0).Resize(myR.Rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set x2 = Union(ws.Cells(2, 3), ws.Cells(14, 3))
' Set xs = SubtractRanges(x1, x2)

End Sub
```

The Code to Subtract 2 Ranges from each other `SubtractRanges(x1, x2)` probably must be be created from scratch. I tried another source, but unfortunately it doesn't work with hidden rows. [For reference see [Subtracting ranges in VBA (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580795/subtracting-ranges-in-vba-excel])

I am open to any suggestions how to achieve this. One idea by myself was to copy the visible cells after filtering to a temporal sheet, do the subtraction there, and then copy the remainder back. The problem with this solution is however that the sequence of rows of the original full sample before any filtering is lost (except the addresses can somehow be saved) and moreover it's always a bit inconvenient to copy stuff around to temporal sheets just to delete them later. What do you think?

The targets in short:

1) apply a filter to the original full sample to create a certain subsample
2) subtract a range from the subsample to get the remainder range
3) deactivate the filter to get the full sample again, with the original order, but at the same time subtracted by the respective range (step 2)

Why not just delete the range in (2) from the full sample? The problem is that by doing that I would not get the correct remainder range, which I need for later work. Imagine I had a full set of 10,000 units, a subset of 100 units and a sub-subset of 40 units to be subtracted from the subset, which in turn would lead to 60 units of remainder range. If I subtracted 40 units from 10,000 units instead, that would lead to 9,960 units, which is not the correct remainder range. I hope that makes the approach more clear.

Comment: Sorry read it three times I can't follow what you are trying to do "Then let's say I want to subtract Cells(2,3) which is B and Cells(14,3) which is N from the remaining square" makes no sense to me :(. At a higher level first can you explain what you what to achieve?

Comment: Not clear about the output...tell more.

Comment: I have added an example to better illustrate what I mean and I also changed the final expected output accordingly

Comment: I removed the code for subtracting ranges because it doesn't work in my case and there was no need to keep it anymore. The reference is still in the thread though if any1 wants to look it up.

Comment: It sounds like you would like, given two ranges A and B, a function which returns the visible cells in A which are not also in B. If this isn't what you are asking for then you need to explain yourself more clearly.

Comment: @JohnColeman That's correct, except for the filtering. The cells in A are not directly connected - there are hidden rows between them. The cells in B however are all part of A. Moreover, is there an easy way to get what you said? Because the only way I figured out was the subtraction of one range from another.

Answer (score 1):

Using an array to store the block of data instead:
Sub TestingStuff()

```
Dim y As Integer
Dim x1 As Range, x2 As Range, xs As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="13"

Dim arr() As Variant
ReDim arr(0 To 2, 0 To rng.Rows.Count)

Set x2 = Union(ws.Cells(2, 3), ws.Cells(14, 3))

j = 0

'Build array
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If rng.Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
        arr(0, j) = rng(i, 1)
        arr(1, j) = rng(i, 2)
        arr(2, j) = rng(i, 3)
        For Each cell In x2
            If cell.Row = i Then
                arr(cell.Column - 1, j) = ""
            End If
        Next cell

        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
ReDim Preserve arr(0 To 2, 0 To j)

Range("E25").CurrentRegion.Clear
Set xs = Range("E25:G" & 25 + j)
xs = Application.Transpose(arr)
'Do whatever you wish with the array
'such as print to another range etc, transpose it etc
'If you wanted it lined up with the original table, you
'wouldnt need to buid an array necessarily - I dont know where you want the output...
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it might be faster to loop over the visibile cells only than to loop and test the condition `if not hidden...` though. Moreover, you didn't apply the method I asked for, which is simple subtraction or the creation of the reverse of a subset. The problem is that after the deletions I want to deactivate the filter and still have the same order as in the original sample. Using your approach I have everything in an array, but not where I want it to be. I need to do more tests. Also your solution is incomplete because it only works on the small example I have shown.

Comment: Ok, I guess like most people I'm not clear on the exact requirements...You want to amend the range and show it as is on the sheet? Then remove the filter, and it goes back to full visible table with deletions?

Comment: yes I believe now you got what I mean. And the amount of rows to loop must be dynamic; it is not always equal to 3, like in the above minimal example.