# excel: find dates in and out of a range

Tags: vba, excel

This is a question that I'm trying to figure it out for a few days.
I have a list of people with dates that they take vacations.

Like this:
[image]

I'm using Advanced Filter with multiple criteria for find dates between two that I insert in my criteria with `>` or `<` and return all the people between this range.

This is the code:

```
Sub FiltroAutomatico()
'
' FiltroAutomatico Macro
'

'
Sheets("BASE_TOTAL_ATUAL").Range("A1:J445").AdvancedFilter Action:= _
    xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("CONSULTA!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range _
    ("CONSULTA!Extract"), Unique:=False
Range("H25").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
Range("G3").Select

End Sub
```

And it works fine with my criteria:

[image]

Translating what I insert in the cells: `>10/02/2017` and `<10/06/2017`.

Here is that my problem starts. When I insert a range, it only return me the values that "begin" and "finish" inside these dates.
If someone hipotetically take vacations from `10/01/2017` to `10/10/2017` or his vacations start at `08/06/2017` and just finish at `15/08/2017` it won't appear in my search.

I'm kind of new at VBA and I didn't find any solution about this problem in my research.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, I don't know if it's possible using just Advanced Filter.

I initially found [THAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580795/subtracting-ranges-in-vba-excel?rq=1) question, but I don't know if it's totally useful for the problem.

Comment: The code does exactly what you ask it to do. Find everything that falls between these ranges. You might want to check if either the start date is within your range, or the end date is within your range. See for an example: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bkmk_4

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, it does... But now I realize it's an excluding code, but for me, if you have a range bigger than that which includes the range that I search for, it should appear too, you know?

Comment: @Luuklag now I saw the article... I guess it "solves" the problem, although I believe it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: It is the way that deviates least from what you are doing. If it is the best way I dont know.

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, I see.. Anyway, thank you, I'll try to do something like that.