# Exclude specific row in the range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to exclude A2:B2 from A1:B5 and store it as a range so that I can use it later. I have the code below which does not return error but does not seem to store anything in the range.

```
Sub ExcludeRange()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newRng As Range
    
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5") 'set the range you want to work with
    Set newRng = rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                               rng.Columns.Count)
                                               
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = newRng
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtracting ranges in VBA (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580795/subtracting-ranges-in-vba-excel)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to exclude A2:B2 from A1:B5

then simply go `Set newRng = Range("A1:B1, A3:B5")`

> Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = newRng

you seem to want to paste a (possible) discontinuous range to a "continuous" one given its upper right cell

you have to loop through `Areas` property of a `Range` object in order to handle all the "sub-Ranges" it's made of

like follows:

```
Sub CopyRangeValue(rangeToPaste As Range, targetCel As Range)

        With targetCel 'reference the upper-right cel of the pasted range
        
            Dim rowOffset As Long
                rowOffset = 0 

                Dim area As Range
                    For Each area In rangeToPaste.Areas ' loop through all the "sub-Ranges" the range to paste is made of
                        .Offset(rowOffset).Resize(area.Rows.Count, area.Columns.Count).Value = area.Value ' paste the current continuous "sub-Range" to the proper target cell

                        rowOffset = rowOffset + area.Rows.Count ' update the paste offset from the target cel
                    Next                    
        End With

End Sub

Sub ExcludeRange()

    Dim newRng As Range
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set newRng = .Range("A1:B1, A3:B5")
        
        CopyRangeValue newRng, .Range("K1")                
    End With
   
End Sub
```